# TxtAnime.js Animation Causes Visual Shifts Among HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I'm encountering a problem with the txtanime.js library that seems to create a noticeable offset between HTML elements on my webpage. I'm using Tailwind CSS for the layout.

Here's the complete code for the page:

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com?plugins=forms,typography,aspect-ratio,line-clamp"></script>
    <link href="https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/031da03967812d134ed68febd3ba78a9?family=GT+America+Regular" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body class="bg-grey-50">
    <section class="flex flex-col md:flex-row">
      <div class="md:w-[65%] w-full h-screen flex flex-col items-center justify-around md:order-last">
        <a href="https://www.lamaisondelhomme.fr" id="logo" target="_blank"><img alt="logo" src="https://www.lamaisondelhomme.fr/wp-content/themes/flatsome/img/landing/logo_lamaisondelhomme_black.svg" width="360" uk-svg /></a>
        <h2 class="break-words text-6xl lg:text-8xl font-semibold text-center mb-4">OUTERWEAR<span class="block text-lg uppercase text-gray-400">sur mesure</span></h2>
        <h3 class="animation text-black uppercase text-5xl"></h3>
        <a href="#test" class="bg-transparent border border-black px-4 py-2 text-2xl font-normal hover:text-white hover:bg-black">En savoir plus</a>
      </div>
      <div class="md:w-[35%] w-full h-[800px] bg-black md:h-screen bg-cover bg-center" style="background-image: url('https://www.lamaisondelhomme.fr/wp-content/themes/flatsome/img/landing/black_friday_outerwear.jpg')"></div>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mohamedfrindi/TxtAnime.js/dist/TxtAnime.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.onload = function (event) {
        new TxtAnime(".animation", {
          effect: "txt-an-9",
          delayStart: 0.2,
          delay: 1.2,
          duration: 0.5,
          repeat: true,
          text: ["Manteau", "Parka", "Trench coat", "Blouson", "Car coat", "Bodywarmer", "Field jacket", "Safari jacket", "Polo coat"],
        });
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The issue arises specifically when using txtanime.js to animate text within the <h3> element with the class .animation. I suspect that positioning the animation block using position: absolute might resolve the problem, but doing so disrupts the flex-based layout used elsewhere on the page.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve this visual discrepancy caused by txtanime.js without compromising the rest of the Flexbox-based layout in Tailwind CSS?

Thank you in advance for any insights or solutions you may provide!

Comment: Looks like the h3 temporarily looses its height, because at the moment it switches from one text to the other, _all_ of the spans it contains are set to `display: none`. I suppose having the text break into multiple lines makes very little sense to begin with for that element - so if you just give it a large enough `height` (probably in em/rem, to keep it somewhat flexible), that should already be enough to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `h3` inside the `div` and give it `min-h-[60px]`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com?plugins=forms,typography,aspect-ratio,line-clamp"></script>
    <link href="https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/031da03967812d134ed68febd3ba78a9?family=GT+America+Regular" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body class="bg-grey-50">
    <section class="flex flex-col md:flex-row">
      <div class="md:w-[65%] w-full h-screen flex flex-col items-center justify-around md:order-last">
        <a href="https://www.lamaisondelhomme.fr" id="logo" target="_blank"><img alt="logo" src="https://www.lamaisondelhomme.fr/wp-content/themes/flatsome/img/landing/logo_lamaisondelhomme_black.svg" width="360" uk-svg /></a>
        <h2 class="break-words text-6xl lg:text-8xl font-semibold text-center mb-4">OUTERWEAR<span class="block text-lg uppercase text-gray-400">sur mesure</span></h2>
        
        <div class="min-h-[60px]">
          <h3 class="animation text-black uppercase text-5xl"></h3>
        </div>
        
        <a href="#test" class="bg-transparent border border-black px-4 py-2 text-2xl font-normal hover:text-white hover:bg-black">En savoir plus</a>
      </div>
      <div class="md:w-[35%] w-full h-[800px] bg-black md:h-screen bg-cover bg-center" style="background-image: url('https://www.lamaisondelhomme.fr/wp-content/themes/flatsome/img/landing/black_friday_outerwear.jpg')"></div>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mohamedfrindi/TxtAnime.js/dist/TxtAnime.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.onload = function (event) {
        new TxtAnime(".animation", {
          effect: "txt-an-9",
          delayStart: 0.2,
          delay: 1.2,
          duration: 0.5,
          repeat: true,
          text: ["Manteau", "Parka", "Trench coat", "Blouson", "Car coat", "Bodywarmer", "Field jacket", "Safari jacket", "Polo coat"],
        });
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```